# How to use DBObject Query in distinct function of mongo template only return count (long)

Tags: java, mongodb, count, distinct, long-integer

I have a distinct query to get a list of elements from db.
How can i implement this method to get only the count of elements as long - second method:

```java
public List distinctElementsByParam(Object param) {
    String collName = mongoOperations.getCollectionName(MyClass.class);
    DBCollection collection = mongoOperations.getCollection(collName);
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("mDBField", param);
    return collection.distinct("myDistinctDBField", query);
}
```

```java
public long distinctCountByParam(Object param) {
    String collName = mongoOperations.getCollectionName(MyClass.class);
    DBCollection collection = mongoOperations.getCollection(collName);
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("mDBField", param);
    return ????;
}
```

Comment: return `collection.distinct("myDistinctDBField", query).size();` which returns `int`. Convert `int` to `Long`

Comment: but then the whole traffic (all Objects in List) are in the response of the db query. i will prevent that.